# Conditional SQL replace

Tags: sql, replace, mariadb

Is it possible to conditionally replace parts of strings in MySQL?

Introduction to a problem: Users in my database stored articles (table called "table", column "value", each row = one article) with wrong links to images. I'd like to repair all of them at once. To do that, I have to replace all of the addresses in "href" links that are followed by images, i.e.,
`<a href="link1"><img src="link2"></a>`
should by replaced by
`<a href="link2"><img src="link2"></a>`
My idea is to search for each "href" tag and if the tag is followed by and "img", than I'd like to obtain "link2" from the image and use it replace "link1".
I know how to do it in bash or python but I do not have enough experience with MySQL.

To be specific, my table contains references to images like

```
<a href="www.a.cz/b/c"><img class="image image-thumbnail " src="www.d.cz/e/f.jpg" ...
```

I'd like to replace the first adress (href) by the image link. To get

```
<a href="www.d.cz/e/f.jpg"><img class="image image-thumbnail " src="www.d.cz/e/f.jpg" ...
```

Is it possible to make a query (queries?) like

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET value = REPLACE(value, 'www.a.cz/b/c', 'XXX') 
WHERE `value` LIKE '%www.a.cz/b/c%'
```

where XXX differs every time and its value is obtained from the database? Moreover, "www.a.cz/b/c" varies.

To make things complicated, not all of the images have the "href" link and not all of the links refer to images. There are three possibilities:

1. "href" followed by "img" -> replace
2. "href" not followed by "img" -> keep original link (probably a link to another page)
3. "img" without "href" -> do nothing (there is no wrong link to replace)

Of course, some of the images may have a correct link. In this case it may be also replaced (original and new will be the same).

Database info from phpMyAdmin

> Software: MariaDB
>
> Software version: 10.1.32-MariaDB - Source distribution
>
> Protocol version: 10
>
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
>
> Apache
>
> Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.15
>
> PHP extension: mysqli

Thank you in advance

Comment: ***Your*** job is to fully and robustly describe what needs to be done.  Unfortunately, your description is neither full nor robust.  Once you accurately describe what you need, what you need to avoid, and the exact behaviour of your data, then we might be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What exactly are you missing? I'll try to describe it once more: For each row in a specific column (called here "value"), I'd like to run a query that replaces all of the href links (first code above) by a string, that is obtained in from the same row. The "value" data are articles containing thousands of characters and some of the links on the images are wrong. Therefore, I'd like to search for each "img src" that is after a "href" link and then replace the "href" address by the address of the image.

Comment: `not all of the images have the "href" link` so what should be done in those cases?  Could there be a rogue href elsewhere in the string?  `and not all of the links refer to images` So, where should we get the source string? Or should we do nothing?  Can there be rogue img tags elsewhere in the string?  Be ***exact*** about ***all cases*** : Categorical criteria for when an action should be taken, and what action should be taken, etc.  If you're ambiguous about what the string can look like, I ***guarantee*** the code will trip up on unexpected cases.

Comment: @Mike.sof Newer versions of MySQL support some advance Regex functions. What is the version you are using ? Please add that detail to the question. Depending on that, there may be some solution.

Comment: Server info added. @MatBailie , thank you for pointing that out, I specified it in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(
    value,
    '^<a href="([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"(.*)$',
    '<a href="\\3"><img class="\\2" src="\\3"\\4'
  )
FROM
  yourTable
```

The replacement only happens if the pattern is matched.

- `^` at the start means `start of the string`
- `([^"]+)` means `one of more characters, excluding "`
- `(.*)` means zero or more of any character
- `$` at the end means `end of the string`

The replacement takes the 3rd "pattern enclosed in braces" (back-reference) and puts it where the 1st "pattern enclosed in braces" (back-reference) was.

The 2nd, 3rd and 4th back-references are replaced with themselves *(no change)*.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=96aef2214f844a1466772f41415617e5

If you have strings that don't ***exactly*** match the pattern, it will do nothing.  Extra spaces will trip it up, for example.

In which case you need to work out a new regular expression that always matches all of the strings you want to work on.  Then you can use the `\\n` back-references to make replacements.

For example, the following deals with extra spaces in the `href` tag...

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(
    value,
    '^<a[ ]+href[ ]*=[ ]*"([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"(.*)$',
    '<a href="\\3"><img class="\\2" src="\\3"\\4'
  )
FROM
  yourTable
```

***EDIT:***

Following comments clarifying that these are actually snippets from the MIDDLE of the string...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=48ce1cc3df5bf4d3d140025b662072a7

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  value = REGEXP_REPLACE(
            value,
            '<a href="([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"',
            '<a href="\\3"><img class="\\2" src="\\3"'
         )
WHERE
  value REGEXP '<a href="([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"'
```

*(Though I prefer the syntax `RLIKE`, it's functionally identical.)*

This will also find an replace that pattern multiple times.  You're not clear if that's desired or possible.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya `REGEXP_REPLACE` was introduced in 10.0.5 : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/

Comment: Thank you very much, but it behaves strangely. Is it possible, that it selects all of the rows, even ones without links, and replaces nothing? I read the documentation and several examples, the command should do exactly what I want but it prints each of the "value".

Comment: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE value REGEXP '<a href="([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"(.*)'` (the same condition) works perfectly but regexp_replace prints all of the rows

Comment: I should emphasise that it prints all of the rows, which is according to documentation, but none of them are changed. When I use the mentioned command just for a search (standard regexp), the rows that are supposed to be replaced (by regexp_replace) are correctly found.

Comment: If you're `REGEXP` in the `WHERE` clause is fine.  Your problem appears to be that you simply were not clear that this text is in the middle of a string.  So lose the `^` and `(.*)$` entirely.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` became available in MySQL 8.0.4, plus an important bug fix in 8.0.12.

Comment: @rick_james : This is for MariaDB, not MySQL. They're forks, sure, but different version numbers, so knowing what version MySQL introduced it is irrelevant...

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks to @MatBailie , but I had to modified his answer. The final query, including the update, is

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET value = REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '(.*)<a href="([^"]+)"><img class="([^"]+)" src="([^"]+)"(.*)', '\\1<a href="\\4"><img class="\\3" src="\\4"\\5'
```

)

A wildcard (.*) had to be put at the beginning of the search because the link is included in an article (long text) and, consequently, the arguments of the replace pattern are increased.

Comment: Without a `\\1` in there, you lose any preceding text... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7eefac6efbe305a578419a78e0eadfbb

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to put it here. Thanks.